# How to go about creating a web application that fits all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a task in front of me where I have to make a web application that will fit all screen sizes, even very large ones like 8k.

Now by fit I don't mean only in terms of layout, but all images, text, buttons, margins, paddings, width, heights, ... everything must scale with the size of the screen. On mobile offcourse the layout changes, but going from a 1080p monitor to an 8k monitor the layout would stay the same only the scale of everything on the screen would become bigger.

Keep in mind that this is a web application not a static web site, so the content is dynamic.

How would one go about developing such an application, without havin a complete mess of a code with breakpoints on every 100px? If anybody knows of a good guide or course, or has himself tackle a similar problem please let me know I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: This is a huge question... Maybe start with a book like [this one](https://abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)?

Comment: The book linked by @NathanArthur is an excellent introductory resource that I highly recommend.  A more immediate and free alternative would be to check out [MDN's primer on Responsive Design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design), or looking up other responsive design tutorials or articles.